# Need to compare two column and provide output to third column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write VBA code that will compare two columns from two different sheets.

I have data in `Sheet1` column `B` and in `Sheet2` column `B`.

The formula to compare both columns is in `Sheet2`: `=B2=Sheet1!B2`.

Could you please help me to write VBA code for the above formula.

I am not sure how to use the above formula in VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

The basic code to compare is

```
If Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet2.Range("B1").Value Then
    'Code to execute when criteria is met
Else
    'Code to execute when criteria is not met
End If
```

The else part is optional and can be omitted if you don't need it

If you want to compare the full column there are a few ways to do it.
My favorite is following:

```
Dim iLastRow As Integer
iLastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp) 'Gets the last row

For i = 1 To iLastRow 'Compares each row and executes the code if 
    If Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value = Sheet2.Range("B" & i).Value Then
        'Code to execute when criteria is met
    Else
        'Code to execute when criteria is not met
    End If
Next i
```

If you want to compare the displayed/formatted text of the cell and not the value behind it use **.Text** instead of **.Value** (e.g. "10th Sep. 2019" instead of 43718)